# Autocomplete dropdownlist not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I went through a lot of guides and stacloverflow posts, but i still don't manage to make it work. I'm still new in javascript, and it's hard for me to figure if it's the script or not.
The main issue i got is the fact I'm not able to debbug it properly, i mean, i can't find where and why it's not working, i just know it doesn't.

Here is my Controller :

```
Entities db = new Entities();

// GET: DynamicListe
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Index(string Prefix)
{
    //Searching records from list using LINQ query  
    var client = (from c in db.Clients
                  where c.Nom.Contains(Prefix)
                  select new { c.Nom });
    return Json(client, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Here is my View :

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#client").autocomplete({
           source: function (request, response) {
               var customer = new Array();
               $.ajax({
                   url: "/DynamicListe/Index",
                   type: "POST",
                   dataType: "json",
                   data: { Prefix: request.term },
                   success: function (data) {
                       response($.map(data, function (item) {
                           return { label: item.Name, value: item.Name };
                       }))
                       for (var i = 0; i < data.length ; i++) {
                           customer[i] = { label: data[i].Value, Id: data[i].Key }
                       }
                   }
               });
               response(customer);
           },
           messages: {
               noResults: "", results: ""
           }
       });
   })
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        <div class="client">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                @Html.TextBox("client")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

I got the right amount of answers (when i press "w" i got 13 results which is correct according to my db), but it's all empty. 
I've tried severals ways to display the json datas, but i don't know how to make it work..

Edit : correct controller and view :

view :

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#client").autocomplete({
           source: function (request, response) {
               var customer = new Array();
               $.ajax({
                   url: "/DynamicListe/Index",
                   type: "POST",
                   dataType: "json",
                   data: { Prefix: request.term },
                   success: function (data) {
                       response($.map(data, function (item) {
                           return { label: item.Text, value: item.Value};
                       }))
                   }
               });
           },
           messages: {
               noResults: "", results: ""
           }
       });
   })
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        <div class="client">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                @Html.TextBox("client")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

controller :

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Index(string Prefix)
{
    List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();
    var client = (from c in db.Clients
                  where c.Nom.Contains(Prefix)
                  select c).ToArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < client.Length; i++)
    {
        list.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = client[i].Nom,
            Value = client[i].ClientID.ToString()
        });
    }
    return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Not related but do not include minified and non-minified versions of the same file (and learn how to use bundles)

Comment: Your not returning objects that have properties `Name` and `Value` and `Key` - your query would need to be `.Select(x => new { Name = x.Something, Value = x.Something, etc })`

Comment: Its also not clear what your trying to do with your `for` loop in the success callback. And you need to delete the `response(customer);` line (that makes no sense)

Comment: I tried with your logic, and it works perfectly, thank you so much ! I still got trouble in the way BundleConfig works, so if you have any tips or good guides ?

Comment: [Bundling and Minification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification)

Answer (score 0):

You're returning your response before it has been received.

In here

```
        source: function (request, response) {
           var customer = new Array();
           $.ajax({
               url: "/DynamicListe/Index",
               type: "POST",
               dataType: "json",
               data: { Prefix: request.term },
               success: function (data) {
                   response($.map(data, function (item) {
                       return { label: item.Name, value: item.Name };
                   }))
                   for (var i = 0; i < data.length ; i++) {
                       customer[i] = { label: data[i].Value, Id: data[i].Key }
                   }
               }
           });
           response(customer);
       },
```

Move the line `response(customer)` inside the ajac `success` callback.

Answer (score -2):

You textbox does not have an ID. you have to add for yout textbox : @Id="client"

Comment: It does have the `id` - thats what `@Html.TextBox("client")` does!
`

Comment: this the name of your textbox. Please check the link : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.textbox(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: And it adds the `id` attribute! You might want to learn the basics of MVC before adding answers here.